# SonataUserBundle FOSUserBundle UniqueEntity email & username

Tags: exception, unique, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have my own User Class, wich inherits Sonata's BaseUser `(Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser)`.

My problem: If I try to create a user from sonata admin using an existing email, I get the following exception:

"Failed to create object: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User"
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
DETAIL: Key (email_canonical)=(test@test.com) already exists.

I tried to use as suggested in some documentations & tickets UniqueEntity using the proper use statements, but to no avail.

I use the UniqueEntity annotation on other entities with sonata admin without a problem, and I'm getting a nice message inside the form which notifies the user that there is already an entity with that name/title instead of the exception. But for the User entity it simply does not work the same way.

This is how I registered sonata user bundle in AppKernel:

```
new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')
```

extending FOSUserBundle

use statements in custom User entity (generated by EasyExtends bundle, just that I've added some custom columns & one to many relations with other entities like ex: Project):

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
```

and this is the annotation for the user class:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("username_canonical")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * @UniqueEntity("email_canonical")
*/
```

this is my config for sonata_user:

```
sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
    class:
        user:  Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
```

this is the config for fos_user:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: admin, user
    user_class:    Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

I'm using a custom admin class

```
parameters:
    #use custom user admin class
    sonata.user.admin.user.class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
```

(I've also tried with the default admin class)

this is my sonata admin configuration:

sonata_admin:
      security:
         handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl
      title: My App
      templates:
        layout: CoreBundle:Admin:standard_layout.html.twig

I have also tried to override validation.yml/validation.xml file with my own validation rules ... but they're ignored or something like that ...

I am out of ideas. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 2):

This made it work for me:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

...
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
...

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User extends AbstractedUser implements UserInterface
...
```

Important lines:

```
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
```